# I am trying to scrap a web page where dynamic dropdowns are available . The 2 nd dropdowns options are not loading while automation script is run

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, dynamic, triggers, dropdown

I am trying to scrap a web page where dynamic dropdowns are available . I have 2 drop downs namely Listing and Type . Listing has two options alpha listing and category listing . TYPE has multiple options from alphabets A to Z for alpha listing . In other words if i select alpha listing from listing the TYPE dropdown will show options from A to Z. while running my automation script to extract these options alpha listing is properly and automatically getting loaded . but the TYPE dropdowns options are not getting loaded properly . instead only select option is present and it is retrieved and printed . When i check it with the website normally i can see the options correctly . But while running my automation script the options of the second dropdown are not loaded . i increased the waiting time , sleep time , allowed it to give multiple attempts , added chrome options , used execute script to trigger the clicking event for TYPE dropdown , tried with Xpath with ID etc etc . No use . I tried to find if any javascript triggers are there in the inspect page . But its huge cudn't figure out . Also there aint any script tag usage in dropdown s definition structure of the html page . It has a class name also . Maybe it can have the code for loading the TYPE dropdown's options . But cudn't find its source or location . If someone could help it would be great . Thanks in advance .

I tried automation the webscraping process of a website . Wanted to load the options of a dynamic dropdown based on another dropdown's selection.

Comment: Share the link of the site and/or attach the source code of the dropdown youre referring to.
It's very hard to help with the information you currently provided